# Android Jetpack Navigation nested tab backward navigation strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

So I'm trying Jetpack navigation component with BottomNavigationView. I created two layer of BottomNavigationView, and the structure looks like this:

- MainActivity (with nav_host_fragment, navigation_graph, bottom_navigation)

  - FragmentA
  - FragmentB
  - FragmentC (with nested_nav_host_fragment, nested_navigation_graph, nested_bottom_navigation)

    - FragmentCA
    - FragmentCB
    - FragmentCC

I have no problem navigating forward, but I couldn't navigate backward properly. 
For example, when I navigation from A -> B -> C, and in C navigate CA -> CB -> CC, then clicking back button or calling navControler back, it should go from CC -> CB -> CA -> B -> A, but it straightly went to A instead.

The minimum demo project can be found [here](https://github.com/Fantasycheese/AndroidNestedNavigationDemo), hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Fragments **do not** pop anything added to the back stack of child fragments.

To get the system back button to pop child Fragments of your Fragment C, you must specifically opt into that behavior by calling [setPrimaryNavigationFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#setprimarynavigationfragment).

This can be done anywhere in your Fragment after your Fragment is attached. For example, you can update your FragmentC to do it in `onActivityCreated()`:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nested_bottom_navigation,
            activity?.findNavController(R.id.nested_nav_host_fragment)?:return)

    // This routes the system back button to this Fragment
    requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(this)
            .commit()
}
```

This is actually the same technique that the `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute on `NavHostFragment` is using under the hood.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! So setPrimaryNavigationFragment() did help, now the pop sequence became CC -> CA -> A, is this the expected behavior of BottomNavigationView? Because what I want to achieve is CC->CB->CA->B->A, any suggestion? And if setPrimaryNavigationFragmet() is the same as app:defaultNavHost="true", why didn't it do the trick as I set it in my fragment_c.xml?

Comment: Yes, that back stack is expected (bottom nav always goes back through the `startDestination` of the graph, but doesn't go through intermediate items). The `defaultNavHost` on your outer `NavHostFragment` makes it primary with the activity's FragmentManager and `defaultNavHost` on your inner `NavHostFragment` makes it primary on your fragment's child fragment manager, but that misses the `NavHostFragment`'s fragment manager (i.e., the FragmentManager each destination is in), so you need to manually set it on that intermediate level.

Comment: FWIW, [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111345778) notes that Navigation will call `setPrimaryNavigationFragment` automatically for you once alpha04 comes out.